# Symfony + Mercure / Server Side Events to Angular 16

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, publish-subscribe, mercure

I have a Symfony backend (BoltCMS) with a custom CaddyServer with the Mercure plugin and I am trying to send a message to my Angular 16 frontend on the event when I save something in the backend so that I can refresh the cache in the Angular application.

I am able to successfully publish the SSE from Symfony to the Mercure/CaddyServer.

However I am having some trouble subscribing to said event. Because I want to authenticate client side subscriptions I cannot use the built in mechanism in Angular if I understood correctly (using EventSource)?

On my search through the internet I found the [ng-sse-client](https://github.com/rubinhos/ngx-sse-client) package with which - according to the [README](https://github.com/rubinhos/ngx-sse-client/blob/master/lib/projects/ngx-sse-client/README.md) - I should be able to pass a authentication token in the header:

```js
...
import { SseClient } from 'ngx-sse-client';
...

constructor(private sseClient: SseClient) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=`);

    this.sseClient.stream('/subscribe', { keepAlive: true, reconnectionDelay: 1_000, responseType: 'event' }, { headers }, 'POST').subscribe((event) => {
      if (event.type === 'error') {
        const errorEvent = event as ErrorEvent;
        console.error(errorEvent.error, errorEvent.message);
      } else {
        const messageEvent = event as MessageEvent;
        console.info(`SSE request with type "${messageEvent.type}" and data "${messageEvent.data}"`);
      }
    });
}
```

However, when I try to call the mentioned function, I get an error, indicating that the function call only accepts 2 erguments instead of 4: `Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 4.`

When I ctrl+click on the stream function to navigate to the function definition, located in `node_modules/ngx-sse-client/lib/sse-client.service.d.ts`, it indeed shows a function which only accepts 2 arguments:

```
stream(url: string, options?: {
        keepAlive?: boolean;
        reconnectionDelay?: number;
        responseType?: 'event';
    }):
```

The weird thing is I am able to find a function definition in another location [sse-client.service.ts](https://github.com/rubinhos/ngx-sse-client/blob/master/lib/projects/ngx-sse-client/src/lib/sse-client.service.ts) which does in fact have 4 arguments. So it looks like I am importing the wrong function or something?

I have looked online, but saw nobody else having similar issues, so I'm thinking I must be doing something wrong, but I've been unable to figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated, either in pointing me in the right direction for an alternative solution/package, or an indication regarding to what I am doing wrong in using this package.

For me it feels weird that something like this is not natively supported in Angular, but I am rather new to Angular, and its quite difficult to find consistent information online, since there are so many different versions with their respective changes.

I have also read about WebSockets, but from what I understood this would be quite overkill for my use-case. But since I have no experience with either SSE or WebSockets, I might be mistaken, and this might be a viable approach?

What I've tried:

I tried calling the SseClient.stream() function with 4 arguments, expecting it to work, but I got an error that it only accepts 2 arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I still haven't found a way to get the [ng-sse-client](https://github.com/rubinhos/ngx-sse-client) to work, after some more digging I have found several solutions to accomplish the sending of an authorization token to Mercure from Angular:

1. Put the token in a Cookie (with a recommended name of `mercureAuthorization`), marked with `Secure`, `HtttpOnly` and `SameSite` (this is the [recommended](https://mercure.rocks/spec#security-considerations) method)
2. Use an EventSource Polyfill, such as this [one](https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource). Using this package with Angular does require an additional step, namely installing the corresponding [types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/event-source-polyfill) to your `devDependencies`, using `npm i --save-dev @types/event-source-polyfill`